# SelectedIndex in two dimensional array

Tags: html, css, angular

```
<div class="outer" *ngFor="let place of hallPlace; let i = index">
    <div [ngClass]="{'seat-reserve' : selectedIndex === (j*i)+j}" class="inner" *ngFor="let spot of place; let j = index" (click)="setPlace((j*i)+j)">
        <span class="content">{{spot}}</span>
     </div>
</div>

  setPlace(seat) {
    this.selectedIndex = seat;
  }
```

I have two dimensional array and I want to add class to selected item, now when I click first element add me style to 1 column, and also when i click random element add me style to few elements. How to add style only one element? And It is possible use array of selectedIndex?

Comment: why not use two variables, iIndex and jIndex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that indexes count starts with `0`, and if you multiply by 0 you get 0

So try `((j+1) * (i+1)) + j + 1` instead of `(j*i)+j`

Comment: I set your pattern but when i click in one elemts style is added to 3 or more elemnts i think for i,j and that ((j+1) * (i+1)) + j + 1 element.

Comment: Hmm I wonder that I have index in outer and inner div and that is problem

Comment: oh well, I guess you shouldn't multiply these indexes, but just make string from them. try `i + ' ' + j`. This one will be unique and only one element will be chosen

Comment: where i should set i + ' ' + j

Comment: `setPlace( i + '  ' + j )` & `{'seat-reserve' : selectedIndex ===  i + '  ' + j }`

Comment: Yes now set only one element, Oleksii it is possible set class to few elements, now when i click in another element class is set to current clicked element, but whene i click two times first and second elements have same class

Comment: in case you want to select multiple items you need to declare `selectedIndexArray: string[]` in your ts file

Comment: You also need few methods like: `getSpotIndex(place: number, spot: number): string { .return place + '  ' + spot; }`, `isSpotSelected(place: number, spot: number): boolean { .return this.selectedIndexArray.includes(this.getSpotIndex(place, spot)) }`,  `togglePlace(place: number, spot: number): void { .if(this.isSpotSelected(place, spot)) { const spotIndex = this.selectedIndexArray.findIndex(this.getSpotIndex(place, spot)); this.selectedIndexArray.splice(spotIndex, 1) } else { this.selectedIndexArray.push(this.getSpotIndex(place, spot)) } }`

Comment: and then in html: `[ngClass]="{'seat-reserve' : isSpotSelected(i, j)}"` ,  `(click)="togglePlace(i, j)"`